# How do i build a node js program/service that stays alive in the background and performs a polling action every few seconds?

Tags: node.js

I'm looking for a way to build a node.js service that runs in the background and polls a Redis Stream (it could be anything really). While i understand how to build a web server in node.js, this "background service that stays alive and polls something (say invokes a REST endpoint or polls a msg queue) every few seconds" is something i have not been able to find. If you can show it in a few lines of code, that'll be awesome

Comment: Just start an interval in an async function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start an interval that to stuff every x seconds

```
startInterval() {
    const x = 1;
    setInterval(() => {
        // Do your Stuff every x seconds here
    }, 1000 * x)
},
```

Comment: Will the process be alive after calling startInterval? It would exit right? I'm not doing this in the browser.

Comment: Thanks folks. It still beats me how a program can be alive without me writing some explicit spinning code. But i tried and apparently BraveButter's answer works. Finally after doing some more research, i decided to use a npm module async-polling which seems to offer a little more features than me rolling my own setInterval

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/).
It is an production process manager for deploying and daemonizing Node.js applications.

In combination with @BraveButter answer you should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may be overthinking this, since Node server processes by default stay alive and actively respond to requests as events. This is in contrast to some server runtime architectures (such as PHP) that will by default have a process per request and so start 
the script 'from scratch' for every new request.

So, in case you are being confused by PHP or somesuch, where you have to jump through extra hoops to create a persistent process, then bear in mind that you shouldn't have to do that for a simple Node server script. You can just set an interval that will run a function every so often using [setInterval](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CronJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron).

Basic Cron Usage from the doc :

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```